# Sending Mail using codeigniter from server

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail

I have application where I want to send mails to clients but i am getting error from server.

[image: Before Scroll]
[image]

Controller code for sending mail

```
        $this->load->library('email');
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.lmsweb.in';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '25';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'support@lmsweb.in';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '****';
    //  $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';

        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from('support@lmsweb', 'LMS');
        $this->email->to($this->input->post('txtvisitoremail'));
        $this->email->subject('Client Login Details');
        $this->email->subject('Congratulation');
        $this->email->send();
       
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        redirect('telecaller/telecaller/update');
```

Same code works when using on localhost but on server I get this error.

After changing protocol to mail I get:

> Message: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1539

I then created a new test mail account, test@lmsweb.in and tried sending mail to it and it worked. So its clear that using mail protocol I cannot send mail to other like Gmail.

Comment: Does adding `$config['newline'] = "\r\n";` and `$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';` help at all?

Comment: @DanielWaghorn no i tried all those settings even tried changing smtp to other protocol

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to send mail from server:

```
function sendEmail($data, $templateName) {
    //echo "<pre>";

    //print_r($data);

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
    $this->email->from($data['from_address']);
    $this->email->to($data['to_address']);
    //$this->email->cc($data['cc_address']);
    $this->email->subject($data['subject']);
    $body = '--------'

    $this->email->message($body);
    $this->email->send();
    $this->email->clear();
    //redirect('web_welcome/member_signup');
}
```

Comment: its using mail protocol of codeigniter and i showed problem when using in this way

Answer (score 0):

In this line you don't have valid address $this->email->from('support@lmsweb', 'LMS'); You are lacking **.in**: support@lmsweb **.in**

Anyway you can use the [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class for sending emails from codeigniter. I've done it by putting the files class.phpmailer.php and class.smtp.php in third party folder and then creating custom library for mail sending:

```
class Mail_sender
{


protected $ci;

var $mail;

public function __construct()
{   
    include (APPPATH. 'third_party/class.phpmailer.php');
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->mail = new PHPMailer ();
    $this->init();

}
public function init(){
    $this->mail->IsSMTP ();
    $this->mail->IsHTML(true);
    $this->mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
    $this->mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $this->mail->Host = 'smtp.t-home.mk'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
    $this->mail->Port = 25;
    $this->mail->SMTPSecure = '';
    $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
    $this->mail->Username = 'user@example.com';       // SMTP username
    $this->mail->Password = 'secret';  //SMTP password
    $this->mail->SingleTo = true; // if you want to send a same email to multiple users. multiple emails will be sent one-by-one.       


}
public function setUsername($username){
    $this->mail->Username = $username;
}

public function setFrom($email, $sender_name)   {

    $this->mail->From = $email;
    $this->mail->FromName = $sender_name;
}

public function setAddress($to){
    $this->mail->addAddress ($to);
}

public function setReplyTo($replyTo)
{
    $this->mail->AddReplyTo($replyTo);
}

public function setSubject($subject){
    $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
    return $this->mail->Subject;
}

public function setBody($messageBody){
    $this->mail->Body = $messageBody;
}

public function sendMail(){
    return $this->mail->Send();
}

}
```

And used a controller for sending mail:

```
$nameSurname=$this->input->post('name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
    $temp_message = $this->input->post('message');
    $message = 'FROM: '.$nameSurname.'('.$email.')<br><br>'.$temp_message;
    $array = array(
        'ime' => $nameSurname,
        'mail' => $email,
        'sub' => $subject,
        'msg' => $message
        );

    $this->load->library('mail_sender');
    $this->mail_sender->setFrom('[from address]','[title]');
    $this->mail_sender->setSubject($subject);
    $this->mail_sender->setAddress("[receiving address]");

    $this->mail_sender->setBody($message);

    $this->mail_sender->sendMail();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, yes i know that i was missing and tried even that and various other ways but no use.

Comment: actually problem seems to be from server side because my client buyed a new mail from google and its working perfectly but mail created by hosting raja only delivers to same domain

Comment: have you tried to send mail from mail client to see if it works that way?

Comment: sorry no idea what you are talking about. I tried creating a test mail account and send mail to that and it worked but its not working for gmail. i.e i can only send to @lmsweb.in.

Comment: mail client program like outlook or mozilla thunderbird.

Comment: i said i can send even from localhost but its not working after publishing on server. Anyways thanks for helping. We have set it up  using google mail.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = Array(
 'protocol' => 'smtp',
 'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
 'smtp_port' => 465,
 'smtp_user' => 'something@mail.com', // change it to yours
 'smtp_pass' => '*******', // change it to yours
 'wordwrap' => TRUE,
  'crlf' => "\r\n",
  'newline' => "\r\n" );
```

it is worked for me after adding last two lines   ''crlf' => "\r\n",
  'newline' => "\r\n"'

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that works for me:

We need to use the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in order to get the Address of the Server In The Controller:

```
public function SendEmail()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');

   $message = '
                    <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Conformation Mail</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <h1>Hello </h1>
                        <h3>New User</h3>
                        <p>tO cHECK THE EMAIL SENT  </p>
                        <p>Thank Your.</p>
                       
                    </body>
                    </html>';
     //Sending email from localhost or live server
    $localhosts = array(
        '::1',
        '127.0.0.1',
        'localhost'
    );
    
    $protocol = 'mail';
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $localhosts)) {
        $protocol = 'smtp';
    }

    $config = array(
        'protocol' => $protocol,
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '**************@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '***************',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n",
    );

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from("************@gmail.com");
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject("New user contacts");
    $this->email->message($message);
    $flag = $this->email->send();

    if($flag){
        echo "Email sent";
        echo '<script>alert("email sent")</script>';
        $this->load->view('main');
    }else{
        echo "Email sending failed";
        echo '<script>alert("mail not sent")</script>';
        $this->load->view('main');
    }
}
```

Now use the controller function to send the email.